# How do I read a text file and store it in an array in C programming (values seperated by a comma)?

Tags: c, arrays

**I need help with getting datapoints, x and y values from a txt file into two arrays.**

Currently, the text file consists of 5 lines like:

0.116

0.118

0.12

0.122

0.124

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main(void) 
{
   FILE *inp;         /* pointer to input file */

   double item;
  int cnt=0,y,d,i;
   double array[300],swap;  

   /* Prepare files for input */
   inp = fopen("testdoc.txt", "r");


   /* Read each item */
   while ( (fscanf(inp, "%lf", &item) == 1) && (!feof(inp)) ) {
     array[cnt] = item;
     cnt++; 
   }


   for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
   {
      printf("%lf\n",array[i]);

   }
   printf("The total number of inputs is %d",cnt);


  fclose(inp); /* Close the files */

  return (0);
}
```

This only reads the first half of the file, which are the x values. Of which output is

0.116000

0.118000

0.120000

0.122000

The total number of inputs is 4

**However,  I want to read a text file and store the values in two different arrays for x and y values.**

The new text file will look like this

0.116,-0.84009

0.118,4.862

0.12,-1.0977

0.122,0.22946

0.124,3.3173

**How do i go changing my code above to recognize the Y values after "," sign? And to add both into two arrays at once?**

Comment: Use fgets and then split the string into numbers for example using strtok or sscanf

Comment: `fscanf(inp, "%lf, %lf", &v1, &v2)`

Comment: @MarcoBonelli have tried adding fscanf(inp, "%lf, %lf", &v1, &v2), but still getting compilation error, not sure what is wrong https://pastebin.com/aPG1zwwb

Comment: Notice that `while (!feof(fp))` is **always** wrong.

Comment: The `feof()` serves no purpose here. Whenever the last call to `fread()` did not fail, `feof()` returns `false`

Answer (score 0):

I tried compiling your code posted on pastebin and received an error because of a missing bracket in your while statement.
That's an easy fix.
The larger issue is in the condition of the while loop.

`fscanf` returns the number of input items converted and assigned on each call.

When you modified your code to return `two` values, the condition in the while loop          `fscanf(inp, "%lf,%lf", &v1,&v2) == 1` would fail and the loop will not be entered.

Please modify the while statement to (*have included the missing "(" too*)..

`while ( (fscanf(inp, "%lf, %lf", &v1, &v2) == 2) && (!feof(inp)) )` 
and you should be good to go!!!

In addition it would be a good practice to include the return type of `int` for the `main` function.